# Moved my opencart site to a new server but now getting warning on session open and not able to login to admin also

Tags: migration, opencart

I have moved my opencart site to a new server (all files & db). Updated the config files with correct file paths and database details.

The site loads but on top of the site im getting a warning message that goes like

> Warning: session_start(): open(/home/users/web/b1869/moo.cineidentitycom/cgi->bin/tmp/sess_15934afd5f2bdfdc7a8f64e3901459bf, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory

The problem is this is trying to open a file from my old server. The path mention in this open command does not exist in my new server.
I tried to clear system cache (delele all files under system/cache) and did the same for vqmod. But still getting this warning.

How do i clear this session, which is still pointing to the old server file path.

Using the current opencart version (1.5.6.4)

Thanks

Comment: This is really weird... Didn't you install some extension for session handling? E.g. some *memcache session handler* or similar? Try clearing your browser cookies (for that domain) as well.